# Copying XML into new directory, creating duplicate, then renaming duplicate file based on inner content

Tags: xml, shell, powershell

I'm very new to Powershell scripting so please forgive my atrocious naming conventions or unnecessary variables. I am trying to extract the information needed from the XML file and rename the file in the new folder as such, but I would like a copy of the original file name as well in the converted folder so as to verify that all documents have been converted and to be able to pin point if any files were missed.

I'm creating this in Windows Powershell ISE (x86). The code below successfully gives copies and moves the files and then renames them, but I'm having issues in the ForEach statement to recursively copy the original file name again and rename the duplicated copy rather than just renaming the moved file.

Any advice on adding the desired feature to the code below, or advice on throwing exceptions for ItemNotFoundException or IOException errors would be greatly appreciated as this will be used to rename some 26000 documents that are highly sensitive.

```
$srcFolder = "C:\NewDocs\*.xml"
$destFolder = "C:\Converted"

$newFolder = Get-ChildItem $srcFolder -Recurse
    Foreach($p in $newFolder) {
       [xml]$xml = Get-Content $p
       copy-item $srcFolder -Destination $destFolder
    }

$convertFolder = Get-ChildItem $destFolder -Recurse
    Foreach ($file in $convertFolder) {
       [xml]$newXML = Get-Content $file
       [string]$NewName = 'User.'+$(newXML.id.extension)
       Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ($NewName + ".xml")
    }
```

actual results

```
C:\NewDocs
Name
1.xml
2.xml
3.xml
4.xml
5.xml

C:\Converted
Name
User.223.xml
User.224.xml
User.225.xml
User.226.xml
User.227.xml
```

I would like the C:\Converted to contain the below results and the C:\NewDocs to stay intact

```
1.xml
2.xml
3.xml
4.xml
5.xml 
User.223.xml
User.224.xml
User.225.xml
User.226.xml
User.227.xml
```

Comment: I do see a syntax error in your `$NewName` assignment. It should be changed to `[string]$NewName = 'User.'+$($newXML.id.extension)` at least. Without seeing an example of xml file contents, it may be hard to fully diagnose the issue.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the XML file contents are confidential due to it being healthcare documents that I am working with. I shortened the XML chain for confidentiality purposes as well as the actual number associated to it for that reason as well, but I can confirm that the number assignment does match each of the tag associated data within the document. My issue is more revolving around the copying the original file names to the new folder and then copying and converting the copied version. Hopefully that clarifies somewhat as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AdminOfThings The original file names involve a 32-bit encrypted sequence, but each of the documents have a 1:1 relation between document and the id within the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have duplicate file names, the following code will work.

```
$srcDir = "C:\NewDocs"
$destDir = "C:\Converted"

mkdir -Path $destDir -Force > $null

Get-ChildItem -Path $srcDir -Filter *.xml -Recurse |
Copy-Item -Destination $destDir -PassThru |
Copy-Item -Destination {
    "{0}\User.{1}.xml" -f $_.Directory, ([xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)).id.extension
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining with a little more detail what is happening within the script? Like I said, I'm pretty new to this and would like to understand the logic for learning purposes.